# Python: I need to include stepping values in the input query within a for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, input

I have to use a for loop to gather data where the user inputs a value:

```
Number of electrodes: 5
Current in Electrode #1: 10
Current in Electrode #2: 211
Current in Electrode #3: 350
Current in Electrode #4: 410
Current in Electrode #5: 220
```

and use a for loop (has to be a for loop) to create prompts for inputs as shown above

currently my code looks like so:

```
cap=int(input("Number of capacitors: "))
for num in range(cap):
    val=num+1
    input("Current in Electrode#",val)
```

but I'm running into issues because you can't have a value in an input statement like that apparently...? I basically don't know how to step through numbers within an input statement created by a for loop. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you:

```
cap = int(input("Number of electrodes: "))
info = []
for i in range(1, cap+1):
    current = int(input("Current in Electrode #"+str(i)+": "))
    info.append(current)

print info
```

This runs as:

```
Number of electrodes: 5
Current in Electrode #1: 45
Current in Electrode #2: 12
Current in Electrode #3: 786
Current in Electrode #4: 120
Current in Electrode #5: 210
[45, 12, 786, 120, 210]
```

This uses a `for` loop to get each number that you want, and then **converts to a string so that we can do string concatenation.** Your problem was probably that you weren't converting to a string first.

Comment: `current` should be `int`.